# Generar y sumar grupos en consulta SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

excelente día, tengo un pequeño problema, estoy realizando una consulta con la cual necesito hacer la suma de un grupo de datos, el problema es el siguiente:

```
UPPER(d.NomUser) AS RUTA, COUNT( distinct (a.CardCode)  ) AS Efectividad, 
cast(a.SyncUpDate as date) fecha1,sum(e.Quantity) Cantidad,sum(e.LineTotal) Total_Venta
   

           FROM VVISI a
           INNER JOIN CUSER d on a.idUsuario = d.idUsuario
           LEFT JOIN VDOCS b on a.idVisit = b.idVisit 
           LEFT JOIN [SBO_GPOTST].dbo.OINV c on b.DocEntry = c.DocEntry and a.CardCode = c.CardCode
           LEFT JOIN [SBO_GPOTST].dbo.INV1 e on B.DocEntry = e.DocEntry 
           where cast(a.SyncUpDate as date) between '2022-12-12' and '2022-12-17'  and a.SalesSuccess>0
   group by  UPPER(d.NomUser), cast(a.SyncUpDate as date)--,substring(e.ItemCode,1,3)
   order by UPPER(d.NomUser), cast(a.SyncUpDate as date);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito agregar una línea mas de código para que agrupe por segmentos, y me saque la suma de los grupos

```
    when substring(e.ItemCode,1,3) >=100 and substring(e.ItemCode,1,3) < 200 then '1' 
    when substring(e.ItemCode,1,3) >=200 and substring(e.ItemCode,1,3) < 300 then '2'
    else '3'
    end as Grupo
```

pero el problema es que me trae la información por todos lados, si poderse agrupar:

necesito que el grupo sea Ruta->Grupo->Fecha->Efectividad->Cantidad->Total_venta
pero al hacerlo me trae la informacion por todos lados. no me da los totales del grupo si no que hace varios totales  y varios grupos.

**Gracias por el apoyo que me puedan dar.**

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Sobre todo, deberías de cambiar la pregunta, para esto puedes usar el link de [edit](/edit), tantas veces como quieras. Elimina las imágenes y pon en su defecto datos. Revisa [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: entiendo que quieres la suma total del total de ventas de cada una de las rutas como una fila adicional?

Comment: ya lo pude resolver, hice un ciclo donde cada uno me hace la consulta por cada grupo. al final solo junto la información.